# Insert in database using data from ListView

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="White">
    <ListView x:Name="ListViewMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding Menus}"
          HasUnevenRows="True"
          BackgroundColor="White"
          SeparatorVisibility="None"
          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
          ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped"
          ItemSelected="Handle_ItemSelected"
          IsGroupingEnabled = "true"
          SeparatorColor="White">
        <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightSkyBlue" HeightRequest="25">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Key}"  FontAttributes="Bold"  LineBreakMode="NoWrap" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                                <Label.FontSize>
                                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                        <On Platform="Android" Value="20"/>
                                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="20"/>
                                    </OnPlatform>
                                </Label.FontSize>
                            </Label>
                            <StackLayout.VerticalOptions>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="LayoutOptions">
                                    <On Platform="Android" Value="Center"/>
                                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="Center"/>
                                </OnPlatform>
                            </StackLayout.VerticalOptions>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Text="{Binding article_description}"
                                       FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="13"  Margin="10,5,0,-6" Grid.Row="0" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding dish_name}" 
                                   FontSize="13" Margin="10,0,0,2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="LabelReserved"  Text="{Binding reserved}" IsVisible="false" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/> 
                            <Switch Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" IsEnabled="False" Toggled="SwitchMenu_OnToggled" >
                                <Switch.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger TargetType="Switch" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference LabelReserved},
                                   Path=Text.Length}" Value="7">
                                        <Setter Property="IsToggled" Value="true" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Switch.Triggers>
                            </Switch>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Menu model , this is how i set the  Menus:

```
public class Menu
{
    public string day { get; set; }
    public string article_description { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string dish_name { get; set; }
    public string Reserved { get; set; }
    public string Meal { get; set; }
};
```

**How I implemented groupHeader:**

First I have all menus in a list called GetGroupedViewMenu.

Then I organize the menus by day of the week:

```
var menus1 = GetGroupedViewMenu.Where(a => a.day == day).ToList();
```

After that i order the list by article_description:

```
var newList = menus1.OrderBy(m => m.article_description).ToList();
```

Then I implement the groupHeader:

```
var sorted = from menu in newList
                     group menu by menu.Meal into menuGroup
            select new Grouping<string, Models.Menu>(menuGroup.Key, menuGroup);

        Menus = new ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, Models.Menu>>(sorted);
```

What I want to do is when I click in the switch, I want to get the info and title (key) from the listview that is in the same row of the switch. I also want toput the info into variables in the code behind, so that I can use the data to insert the data into a database. How can I do that?

Comment: tried creating a bool property in the model and binding this to the Setter's value?

Comment: What the bool property does?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several solutions here:

1. The simplest but most ugly way , find the switch's parent and BindingContext

   ```
   private void Switch_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
   {
       Switch sw = sender as Switch;
       ViewCell cell = sw.Parent.Parent as ViewCell;
       object obj = cell.BindingContext;

       //do the db action
   }
   ```
2. create a subclass of Switch with a BindableProperty

SubClass :

```
public class MySwitch : Switch
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ConfigurationItemProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: "ConfigurationItem", returnType: typeof(Item), declaringType: typeof(Switch), defaultValue: null);
    public Item ConfigurationItem { //Item is the class contained in your list.
        get{ return (Item)GetValue(ConfigurationItemProperty);}
        set { SetValue(ConfigurationItemProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

XMAL:

```
<ViewCell.View>
    <StackLayout>
        <local:MySwitch  ConfigurationItem ="{Binding}"  Toggled="Switch_Toggled" />
    </StackLayout>
</ViewCell.View>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void Switch_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
{
    MySwitch sw = sender as MySwitch;
    Item item = sw.ConfigurationItem;
    //do the db action
}
```

#### PS: What i have tried at beginning

I found `ClassId`(BindableProperty) defined in `Element` , my original idea is add a index property into the viewModel ,bind it with ClassId ,and I can figure it out code behind, but no luck it doesn't work, the index always gets null.

```
<Switch  ClassId="{Binding index}" Toggled="Switch_Toggled" />

private void Switch_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
{
    Switch sw = sender as Switch;
    string index= sw.ClassId;
    //do the db action
}
```

Comment: Creating the subclass i have error on "Item", says :"Name item cannot been found"

Comment: @Phill Item is the model class name in the list (Menus)

Comment: @Phill how you set Menus, could you attach the code .

Comment: Added Menu model.

Comment: where is the `key` property , what does  itemsource look like  to implement  GroupHeader,

Comment: Added to the post the implementation of the groupHeader, the Meal is "Dinner" and "lunch", article_description is "Fish", "Meat" , etc...

Comment: @Phill change `Item` to `Menu`, have you solved your problem?

Comment: I dont understand how this is woking, but is working, thanks alot.